# How to configure eth0 as point to point

Tags: raspbian, networking, ethernet

I'm porting a software from Windows to Linux and I must connect my RPi4 to a microcontroller via ethernet.
These are the connection parameters:

IP Address: 10.10.20.1
Subnet Mask: 255.240.0.0

Gateway: -
DNS 1,2: -

[image: My ethernet configuration dialog]

This is my dhcpcd.conf, Raspbian default with a static ip set for eth0

```
hostname
clientid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private

interface eth0
inform 10.10.20.1/12
```

I also tried this, but with no success:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=10.10.20.1/12
```

but I still can't ping the microcontroller at 10.10.20.10

Any ideas?

Comment: Firewall is enabled and doesn't allow ICMP?! They are on different layer 2 network, do you have a switch with management and different VLAN on the switch ports? Otherwise they are on the same IP network.

Comment: I didn't configure the firewall on Raspbian, but I don't think that should be a problem. I'm connected to the RPi with vnc via wifi and I can ping my notebook.
And the Pi should be on the same IP network of the microcontroller, whose address is 10.10.20.10

Comment: Can the Windows PC ping the controller?  Very few of the ones I've used had to link to had Ping built in despite having Ethernet (grrrr).  Can you please edit your question and add your dhcpcd.conf and output of `ip link` in code blocks?  Have you tried adding a static routers line with the gateway address in dhcpcd.conf if no gateway try `nogateway` Any VLANs involved?

Comment: Do you have both the WiFi and Ethernet on the same sub-net?

Comment: @Andyroo Yes, Windows can ping the micro and the WiFi is on a different subnet

Comment: With **nogateway** I can ping the micro!
It does not work yet, but now I could very well be other stuff rather than the network settings